# HTML Calendar form and input arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

EDIT take 2:

Each "calendar_date" is an object with attributes "customer" and "check-in".
What is the best way to show multiple "calendar_date"s in a form where attributes "customer" and "check-in" can be updated for each date?

Do...

```
  <input type="text" name="customer[<?php echo $calendar_date?>]" />
  <input type="text" name="check-in[<?php echo $calendar_date?>]" />
```

For each date?

This creates 2 separate PHP arrays $customer and $check-in for every date where the date is the index key and the value is the form input for that field.

Is this a good approach or is there a better approach?

I feel there has to be a better option.  My concern involves processing a whole year at once (which can happen) and adding additional text input fields.

Comment: I have a suggestion. don't use ugly quote-delimited strings for outputting large amounts of HTML but write it as is.

Comment: As for your question, do you have any problems at the moment? If so - why don't you anounce them. If no - what is the reason for this question?

Comment: I updated my question.  The problem at the moment is bloat.  How can it be reduced?  And efficiency.  How can it be gained?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I don't quite understand the question is yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is either. If you just need the same value to be put in multiple places, you can skip the bloated HTML with many input fields, get that value once and append it where you need when you're processing the POST/GET with PHP.

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't clear in my question.  Please check the new edit.  Each date will have unique values and multiple dates will be processed at once from the same form.

Comment: Sorry. Question wasn't clear.  Architecture has since been reworked. Agree on skipping the bloated HTML...